# Make a calculation using the results of 2 different queries

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon. I have been trying to take the results of 2 different queries, in php, and divide them to get the percent complete which I plan on echoing on to an existing page. Below are the queries and code I have so far, but I only get an output of 0. When I try to echo either of the result variables by themselves, nothing appears on the site, so for some reason it isn't pulling the value from the sql statements to begin with. All help is greatly appreciated.

```php
$sql1 = "
    SELECT format(COUNT(*),0) AS total 
      FROM ttb_books 
     WHERE owned = 1
    ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$books_owned = floatval($row1["total"]);

$sql2 = "
    SELECT format(COUNT(DISTINCT(ttb_books.book_id)),0) AS book_samples 
      FROM ttb_books
      JOIN ttb_imgs 
        ON ttb_books.book_id = ttb_imgs.book_id
     WHERE ttb_books.owned = 1
    ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$book_samples = floatval($row2["book_samples"]);


$sample_percent = $book_samples/$books_owned;

echo "$sample_percent";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Please stop using this ancient, insecure, and deprecated API !!

Comment: What is `$book_samples` and `$books_owned`?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing strings and floats which can really ask for problems.

Specifically, by using `format(COUNT(*),0)` in your SQL you are asking for the number as a string, so for instance `1000` would come back as `1,000`. You are then passing that to the float parser [which has a whole section dedicated to it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

There's [also a warning in the return section for `floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php#refsect1-function.floatval-returnvalues) that says:

> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string

I just ran this sample code as a demo:

```php
$a = "1,000";
$b = floatval($a);
echo $b; // Prints 1
```

If you can, first avoid using the format in your SQL, that will give you true numbers to work with. If you want to format the number for display, so that when you actually need to.

Second, for debugging purposes, output those two numbers to see if they are what you think they are. These should only contain digits, no commas.

`echo $book_samples . "\n" . $books_owned;`

*edit*

Before I get too far, I'm not 100% certain that you can mix-and-match `mysqli_query` with `mysql_fetch_array`. Pick one and stick to it (and as @Strawberry pointed out, pick `mysqli`).

If I'm wrong on that, for additional troubleshooting, make sure you have error display completely enabled. Then, make sure to test the output of each of those functions

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql1 = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total 
      FROM ttb_books 
     WHERE owned = 1
    ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
if(!$result){
    die('Error querying');
}
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
if(!$row1){
    die('Error fetching');
}
print_r($row1);
$books_owned = $row1["total"];
echo $books_owned;

$sql2 = "
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ttb_books.book_id)) AS book_samples 
      FROM ttb_books
      JOIN ttb_imgs 
        ON ttb_books.book_id = ttb_imgs.book_id
     WHERE ttb_books.owned = 1
    ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
if(!$result2 ){
    die('Error querying 2');
}
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
if(!$row2 ){
    die('Error fetching 2');
}
print_r($row2);
$book_samples = $row2["book_samples"];
echo $book_samples;
```

Comment: removing the format from the sql statements, and using your echo string, I only get 0s. I should be getting about 1500 for books_owned, and around 198 for book_samples. When I run the sql statements individually in phpmyadmin, I get the results I want, so the issue is where it is pulling and preparing the data for display.

Comment: Because `COUNT()` returns an int (technically a BIGINT), you can switch to `(int)` or `intval()` which will remove some of the float nastiness. Also, do a `print_r($row1)` right after it is loaded to see what is in there.

Comment: No output again. I removed the float, the format within the sql, and nothing appears. I still get results running the dql in phpmyadmin, but it's not porting out

Comment: Ok, using your code (and even before when I changed my fetch to mysqli), I get the $books_owned value to display. For samples I get Error querying, even though it works in phpmyadmin. So its the 2nd query causing the break

Comment: I'm sure you cannot mix these APIs

Comment: @Aaron, when you get an error you can use [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) which will give you the text of the last error.

Comment: @Strawberry, I was pretty certain, too, but I would have expected the code to explode much earlier with a non-recoverable error or something.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array was changed to mysqli_fetch_array, and is working for the sql1 query. it is the sql2 query that isnt passing a value for output, but I dont see any errors in the query as I am getting output in phpmyadmin directly.

Comment: @Aaron, I've updated the code above with another shot at debugging, you really just need to step through it line-by-ilne, and the most common way to do that is to print/dump/echo to screen at every step of the way. If you have no errors, then the results of `$row2` and `$row1` are probably the most interesting

Comment: jesus, just shoot me. the dumbest thing, which you cant see from my paste. It was a space. smh. a stupid space causing a query line to run in to the next when it was trying to execute. it works now. thank you for your help, everyone. It's advil time.

Comment: @Aaron, this won't be the last time it happens, I promise! At our agency, we call that [Duck Talking](https://vendiadvertising.com/insight/duck-talking) and we do it on a daily basis just to keep sane!